# How to access data from machine using google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to use google colab. But my data is pretty huge. So I want to access my data directly from the machine in google colab. And I also want to save the files directly in my machine directory. Is there a way I can do that as I can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how to use local runtime here.

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Otherwise, you can store your data on GDrive, GCS, or S3. Then, you can just mount it, no need to upload every time.